# Why I can't assign variables with constructor and get the wrong value from it?

Tags: c++, class

I would like to implement a BST in C++, but I found that the integer variable "val" I pass in the constructor "Node()" seem not to work properly.
P.S. I am a totally newbie to this language, and here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class Node{

    public:
        int val;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        // the constructor
        Node(int val){
            val = val;
            left = nullptr;
            right = nullptr;
        }
};

class BST{
    public:
        Node *root;
        BST(){
            root = nullptr;
        }
        void insert(int val);
};

void BST::insert(int val){
    if (root == nullptr){
        root = new Node(val);
        cout << root->val << endl; // output: 40580256(this number changes every time I run the code) 
        delete root;
    };
    
    if (root->val == val){
        cout<<"The value: " << val << " is duplicated!" << endl;
    }

}

int main() {
    BST bst;
    Node a = Node(10); // output: 8
    cout << a.val << endl;;
    bst.insert(8);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

It only works when I directly assign the variable "val" to root.val instead of using constructor to assign.

Comment: `val = val;` is your problem.  What do you think that line does?  Can you [explain to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what that line does?

Comment: You probably meant `this->val = val;`

Comment: Put another way, how do you think that the compiler can tell whether `val` refers to the parameter `val` or the member variable `val`? Obviously it cannot read your mind and know what you intended.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, now I change the parameter name from "val" into "value" and it works properly. Also another solution to use "this" operator works as well! Love the strong community : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're having a problem is outlined in the comments, but, stylistically, it's better to do this:

```
class Node{

    public:
        int val;
        Node *left = nullptr;
        Node *right = nullptr;
        // the constructor
        Node(int val) : val (val) { }
};
```

Now, nothing can go wrong.

Comment: This works like magic!! But what's the mechanism behind it?

Comment: The magic is "as if" the identifiers are resolved like (pseudo-code): `Node(int param_val) : this->val (param_val) { }`

Comment: When you use an initialiser list, rather then explicit assignments in the constructor, the compiler knows what each `val` means from the context, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: *Now, nothing can go wrong.* We will find a way to <expletive deleted> things up. We always do.

Comment: @user4581301 Absolutely 

Comment: I've figured it out, thank you guys!